# Linear least squares in scipy - accuracy of QR factorization vs other methods

Tags: scipy, linear-algebra

I have tried solving a linear least squares problem Ax = b in scipy using the following methods:

```
x = numpy.linalg.inv(A.T.dot(A)).dot(A.T).dot(b) #Usually not recommended
```

and

```
x = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, b)
```

both give almost identical results. I also tried manually using the QR algorithm to do so ie:

```
Qmat, Rmat = la.qr(A)

bpr = dot(Qmat.T,b)
n=len(bpr)
x = np.zeros(n)
for i in xrange(n-1, -1,-1):
    x[i] = bpr[i]
    for j in xrange(i+1, n):
        x[i] -= Rmat[i, j]*x[j]
    x[i] /= Rmat[i,i]
```

This method, however, gives very inaccurate results (errors on the order of 1e-2). Have I made a n00b mistake with the code or maths? Or, is the an issue with the method, or scipy itself?

My numpy version is 1.6.1 (the mkl compiled version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), with Python 2.7.3 on x86_64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using those binaries, the QR factorization is computed by Intel MKL, and is probably correct.

For me the above code gives solutions within `1e-12` of the correct result, for random matrices. What matrixes did you test it with, and how do you measure the error?

There are cases in which the least squares problem is ill-conditioned. For instance,
for a matrix with a large null space, rounding errors can affect the result. Consider the rank-1 matrix:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
v = np.random.rand(100)
A = v[:,None] * v[None,:]
b = np.random.randn(100)

x = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0]
print(np.linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b))
# -> 9.63612833771

# xp obtained using your above code
print(np.linalg.norm(A.dot(xp) - b))
# -> 3262.61161684
```

Your home-brewn triangular solve is more suspectible to rounding error than the more carefully written LAPACK routine used in lstsq, so it will be somewhat less accurate.

Comment: I am using the above code for a least-squares sinusoidal curve fit, so my A matrix looks something like `A=numpy.c_[cos(a*t), cos(b*t), cos(c*t), sin(a*t), sin(b*t), sin(c*t)]` where t is an evenly spaced M length vector. Also the differences between a,b and c are much greater than dt*M. Doesn't this mean the columns of A are almost orthogonal, and the matrix is full rank?

Could there be other factors influencing the roundoff error?

Comment: If your matrix only has 6 columns, it is full rank only if the length of vector `t` is also 6. Moreover, you didn't specify how are you measuring the error in the solution.

Comment: What you can do here is to post a complete runnable code, and say what it outputs for you.

Comment: I was only looking at the differences between the solved b vector values (which were order 1e-2 as stated) and the exact ones. I wasnt calculating RMS error or anything. Anyway I have been unable to reproduce the error since then - it may have been due to a dodgy dataset. For now, this looks like the most likely cause - If I can reproduce the error I'll post back here.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try using truncated eigendecomposition . That mean using top k eigen value .I used the following code to regularized least square regression , y=kc

[image]

where `u` is eigenvector and `lambda`is eigenvalue

kernel matrix for linear model:

```
k=np.dot(X,X.T)
```

then eigendecompostion:

```
 w, v = scipy.linalg.eigh(k, eigvals=(lo, hi))
```

then

```
temp= np.dot(np.dot(v,np.diag(1.0/w)),v.T)
c=np.dot(temp,y)
```

also for regularization you you should add a small value (like `0.001`) to the diagonal of kernel matrix, otherwise you would have negative eigenvalues which prevent your kernel matrix of not being positive definite.

Comment: Truncated SVD may be a numerically better choice than truncated eigendecomposition.

Comment: haven't used it ,but can you tell me why?interested to know

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=svd+least+squares --- it's more or less the same, but less rounding error, probably more efficient, and the regularization is better controlled

Comment: [TruncatedSVD class](https://machinelearningmastery.com/singular-value-decomposition-for-machine-learning/) scroll down the link