# SVD Decomposition for linear equation solving

Tags: python, scipy, svd

looking for [Algo here](https://www.ltu.se/cms_fs/1.51590!/svd-fitting.pdf) & trying to implement [this code](https://sthalles.github.io/svd-for-regression/), I'm getting different `l2-norms` for resulting vectors of params for linear equation. Where am I mistaken in my attempt to adopt the code?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

np.random.seed(123)
v = np.random.rand(4)
A = v[:,None] * v[None,:]
b = np.random.randn(4)

x = linalg.inv(A.T.dot(A)).dot(A.T).dot(b) #Usually not recommended because of Numerical Instability of the Normal Equations  https://johnwlambert.github.io/least-squares/
l2_0= linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)
print("manually: ", l2_0)

x = linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0]
l2_1= linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)
print("scipy.linalg.lstsq: ", l2_1)

# 2-norm of two calculations compared
print(np.allclose(l2_0, l2_1, rtol=1.3e-1))

def direct_ls_svd(x,y):
  # append a columns of 1s (these are the biases)
  x = np.column_stack([np.ones(x.shape[0]), x])

  # calculate the economy SVD for the data matrix x
  U,S,Vt = linalg.svd(x, full_matrices=False)

  # solve Ax = b for the best possible approximate solution in terms of least squares
  x_hat = Vt.T @ linalg.inv(np.diag(S)) @ U.T @ y
  #print(x_hat)

  # perform train and test inference
  #y_pred = x @ x_hat
    
  return y-x @ x_hat     #x_hat

x= direct_ls_svd(A, b)
l2_svd= linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)
print("svd: ", l2_svd)

# LU
x= linalg.solve(A.T@A, A.T@b)
l2_solve= linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)
print("scipy.linalg.solve: ", l2_solve)

# manually:  2.9751344995811313
# scipy.linalg.lstsq:  2.9286130558050654
# True
# svd:  6.830550019041984
# scipy.linalg.solve:  2.928613055805065
```

if my error is in SVD-decomposition Algorithm imlementation for solving Least-Squares problem or perhaps in Numpy relative Scipy [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16078114/15893581) or precision differences ? How to correct svd-algo for Least-Squares to become compareable with scipy's? And will this algorithm be faster & less memory-consuming than Iterative Least-Squares methods?

P.S.
[SVD](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-scipylinalgsvd-in-python) applications or [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee127/sp21/livebook/l_svd_main.html#:%7E:text=The%20singular%20value%20decomposition%20%28SVD%29%20generalizes%20the%20spectral,matrix%29%2C%20to%20any%20non-symmetric%2C%20and%20even%20rectangular%2C%20matrix.), [SVD for PCA](https://machinelearningmastery.com/singular-value-decomposition-for-machine-learning/) & [PLS-SVD](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partial-least-squares-singular-value-decomposition-plssvd/) is my final goal -- will be the algo the same as for Least-Squares approximation ? I'm confused with such a question in general (even with code examples). Can somebody add some clarity for newbie like me, please?

P.P.S.
applying [such implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292892/15893581) - I'm getting even worse result: `svd:  10.031259300735462` for l2-norm

P.P.P.S.
also I lack some understanding of [svd in singular spectral decomposition](https://www.bing.com/search?q=svd+in+singular+spectral+decomposition&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE11SR) if exists [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987056/does-the-singular-value-decomposition-coincide-with-the-spectral-decomposition-f), as 1st for unsupervised dim.reduction & 2nd for non-parametric TS analisys, [for practice](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318066716_Linear_Algebra_Theory_and_Algorithms)

P.P.P.P.S. ! PCA is used preliminary estimating if Multicollinearity exists, otherwise strange results can get (biased etc.)... (if no collinearity => no sensitivity to error of estimation, aka shown in small condition number of OLS analysis, - vc.vs huge cond.num.==collinearity for multivariable/multidimensional regression)

Comment: [algo for 2d A](https://andreask.cs.illinois.edu/cs357-s15/public/demos/09-svd-applications/Least%20Squares%20using%20the%20SVD.html) also gives `l2-norm` different from previous

Comment: additionaly, [other approaches](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs357/su2014/lectures/lecture09.pdf)

Comment: `A` can take any 2D: e.g. `np.random.seed(12); A = np.random.randn(6, 4); b = np.random.randn(6); print(A)` ... Concerning `x_hat` you're right. Thanks

Comment: P.S. [2.7 Fitting Ellipses](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2014/other/linalg_INFK/svdneu.pdf)

Comment: [PCA with SVD](https://github.com/jinhangwang/csmath/blob/master/hw2/hw2_pca.py)

Comment: Speed [Comparing _ decompositions for solving least squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040363/comparing-lu-or-qr-decompositions-for-solving-least-squares)

Comment: [plot PCA fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888553/fitting-a-line-through-3d-x-y-z-scatter-plot-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important part here is to filter out the singular vallues that are `0`. For your example data `S` is `[9.22354602e-01 3.92705914e-17 1.10667017e-17 5.55744006e-18]`, notice that you have one singular value close of `~9.22` and the other three are tiny (`< 1e-16`).
If you attempt to reconstruct the solution using the small errors some elements of `Vt` and `U`, that should be about the same magnitude will get divided by these small values and will add up to a significant error to the result.

What can be done in this case is, you assume that any singular value that are small enough are an exact zero. In the following modified version of your function I am assuming all the singular values that are less than `rcond` times the maximum singular value should be zero. Then I compute a mask `m` and drop the corresponding rows and columns of the `U` and `Vt` matrices.

```
def direct_ls_svd(A,b,rcond=1e-7):
  # calculate the economy SVD for the data matrix x
  U,S,Vt = linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
  # Mask to remove the zeroes
  m = (abs(S) / np.max(abs(S))) > rcond
  U, S, Vt = U[:,m], S[m], Vt[m, :]
  assert np.allclose( U @ np.diag(S) @ Vt, A)
  # solve Ax = b for the best possible approximate solution
  # in terms of least squares
  x_hat = Vt.T @ ((U.T @ b) / S)
    
  return x_hat
```

An alternative solution is to set `S[m]=0` then you could avoid an extra copy in the worst case, but you lose the potential savings from the reduction of the number of multiplications in the very low rank cases.

Comment: Interesting, that with `A`  in my comment above (to open post) - also works OK QR-factorization for LS like `def ls_qr(A,b, n): Q, R = linalg.qr(A, mode="full"); x_qr = linalg.solve_triangular(R[:n], Q.T[:n].dot(b), lower=False); return x_qr` being called with `x_qr= ls_qr(A,b, A.shape[-1])`, & res with `l2_qr= linalg.norm(A.dot(x_qr)-b, 2)` ... but with `A` from open-post such QR-func gives NOT correct `l2_qr=21`-- I'm confused whether the reason can be the same - filtering for some zeros?

Comment: Yes the reason is the same note that `np.diag(R) = [-6.68884090e-01,  3.63367716e-17,  1.19851509e-17,  7.64746752e-18]`

Comment: [this QR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620007/15893581) works for both, and sometimes better [lstsq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733070/15893581), then `solve`

Comment: I think, I understood the idea - it goes from [independence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25476183/15893581) if I understood correct?... and when [eigenvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25833792/15893581)=0 we remove such directions of variance, as dependent (or collinear), -- that is SVD-method use in PCA... –

Comment: for the info: [implement-a-pca-using-svd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508233/python-implement-a-pca-using-svd?rq=3)

Comment: QR Application: Generalized Minimum Residual ([GMRES](https://johnwlambert.github.io/least-squares/)) algorithm solving large, sparse linear systems - with *Rotation*

Comment: Yes, `A @ x` would be invariant to perturbations of X in the directions of the right eigenvectors of A associated with eigenvalues 0. That boils down to the definition of null-space.

Comment: [remark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132260/15893581), that "Actually, svd is used in the lstsq but not in the same matrix."

Comment: last Q? As I see: for approximation/optimizatiom algos - if Obj.Func is Non-Convex because of `matmul` (e.g. working with algo LS `(r(ui)-matmul(x(u)^T,y(i))**2` ), then it’s `NP-hard` (as Grad.Descend iters are slow) & we'd better transform task to Convex - saw advice to use x & y as features for separate learnings iteratively checking final obj.func to converge (`Alternating LS` for Recommender system e.g.) - could such algo be `Cross-Decomposition` (as `Partial LS`), could this bagging be done with boosting & is result trustable [of such separate factorization, then LS], from your practice?

Comment: This is a very broad question for a comment, I studied something similar in the past (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9261108) depending on what x(u) and y(i) are it can be simplified. If the system has large enough dimension then the non-convexity should not be a big problem in practice. For small dimensional problems adding slack variables to a relaxed problem may help you to find good solutions to the original one, in some cases even an optimal solution.

Comment: really, I need to pay more attention to [Linear Matrix Inequalities](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/21/9/3285) in context of [Explainable Artificial Intelligence](https://www.mdpi.com/topics/TEYLN2388R). Thank you for the direction!

Comment: [LMI Techniques in Optimal Control](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-030-44184-5_207) "LMI (linear matrix inequality) techniques offer more flexibility in the design of dynamic linear systems than techniques that minimize a scalar functional for optimization." - sounds like to be faster for State-Space models... But what algo implements this faster approach ? - [Q-learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.00779.pdf) or tensorflow'LSTM- to be faster? Anyway, including factorization to Neural Network architecture, I hope,  speed up either implementation of above mentioned !?

Comment: OK, [different inequalities](https://web.mit.edu/braatzgroup/33_A_tutorial_on_linear_and_bilinear_matrix_inequalities.pdf) exist & [stability problem of multidimensional systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377042720306543) is still under the discussion, or [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11768-021-00061-z). Really, awesome topic. P.S. [LSTM stabilization using LMI](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332810528_Long-Short_Term_Memory_Neural_Network_Stability_and_Stabilization_using_Linear_Matrix_Inequalities)

Comment: LMIs are SDP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming, are for small dimension problems. If you can modularize your model and analyse many parts separately it may work. But as far as I know, it is not currently possible to beat first order optimization algorithms on deep learning.

primal dual interior point solvers are more accurate. But take a look in alternating projections algorithm https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/alt_proj.pdf (since you mentioned alternating LS)